# How do I add a new sourceset to Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, build, integration-testing, source-sets

I want to add integration tests to my Gradle build (Version 1.0). They should run separately from my normal tests because they require a webapp to be deployed to localhost (they test that webapp). The tests should be able to use classes defined in my main source set. How do I make this happen?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

**Update for 2021:**

A lot has changed in 8ish years. Gradle continues to be a great tool. Now there's a whole section in the docs dedicated to configuring Integration Tests. I recommend you [read the docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:configuring_java_integration_tests) now.

**Original Answer:**

This took me a while to figure out and the online resources weren't great. So I wanted to document my solution.

This is a simple gradle build script that has an intTest source set in addition to the main and test source sets:

```
apply plugin: "java"

sourceSets {
    // Note that just declaring this sourceset creates two configurations.
    intTest {
        java {
            compileClasspath += main.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    intTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    intTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

task intTest(type:Test){
    description = "Run integration tests (located in src/intTest/...)."
    testClassesDir = project.sourceSets.intTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = project.sourceSets.intTest.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Comment: You'll still need to declare and configure an integration test task. In terms of documentation, there is a `java/withIntegrationTests` sample in the full Gradle distribution.

Comment: Thanks @PeterNiederwieser I've corrected my sample build script.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Thanks - could you please link it up? I also find this exact situation severely lacking in docs: It is all well and good defining a new sourceSet, but no info about "hooking this into" the actual compile, jar, test and whatnot targets - as this example does (except for adding into the jar, or making a new jar, out of that sourceSet).

Comment: On line 6, I get "Cannot resolve symbol 'java'" when using IntelliJ.  Any thoughts on why?

Comment: I would expect the java symbol to be defined in line 1. Is that present? If you're using a newer version of Gradle they may have change the implementation of sourceSets. If so, you'll need to check the appropriate docs.

Comment: @stolsvik https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/docs/src/samples/java/withIntegrationTests

Comment: I see only one difference to the doc https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:configuring_java_integration_tests at the configurations block, any reason why?

@herman interesting enough this samples doesn't match the documentation ;(

Answer (score 35):

Here is how I achieved this without using `configurations{ }`.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6

sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/integrationtest/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/integrationtest/resources'
        }
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    }
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    description = "Runs Integration Tests"
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
    classpath += sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
}
```

***Tested using:** Gradle 1.4 and Gradle 1.6*

Comment: while `java {
            srcDir 'src/integrationtest/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/integrationtest/resources'
        }` is not relevant since it just redeclares `src/<sourceSetName>/...` to `src/integrationtest/...`: here: change the capital T to a lower t

Comment: Beware of this approach. `compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath` is combining two sets of files. There is no usual conflict resolution for dependencies. You can end up with two versions of the same library. Extending configurations will help with that.

Answer (score 25):

> This was **once written for Gradle 2.x / 3.x in 2016 and is far outdated**!!
>   Please have a look [at the documented solutions in Gradle 4 and up](/a/54695537/529977)

---

To sum up both old answers (get best and minimum viable of both worlds):

some warm words first:

1. first, we need to define the `sourceSet`:

   ```groovy
   sourceSets {
       integrationTest
   }
   ```
2. next we expand the `sourceSet` from `test`, therefor we use the `test.runtimeClasspath` (which includes all dependenciess from `test` AND `test` itself) as classpath for the derived `sourceSet`:

   ```groovy
   sourceSets {
       integrationTest {
           compileClasspath += sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
           runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath // ***)
       }
   }
   ```

   - **note**) somehow this redeclaration / extend for `sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath` is needed, but should be irrelevant since `runtimeClasspath` always expands `output + runtimeSourceSet`, don't get it
3. we define a dedicated task for just running integration tests:

   ```groovy
   task integrationTest(type: Test) {
   }
   ```
4. Configure the `integrationTest` test classes and classpaths use. The defaults from the `java` plugin use the `test` `sourceSet`

   ```groovy
   task integrationTest(type: Test) {
       testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
       classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
   }
   ```
5. *(optional)* auto run after *test*

   ```
   integrationTest.dependsOn test
   ```
6. *(optional)* add dependency from `check` (so it always runs when `build` or `check` are executed)

   ```groovy
   tasks.check.dependsOn(tasks.integrationTest)
   ```
7. *(optional)* add java,resources to the `sourceSet` to support auto-detection and create these "partials" in your IDE. i.e. IntelliJ IDEA will auto create `sourceSet` directories java and resources for each set if it doesn't exist:

   ```groovy
   sourceSets {
        integrationTest {
            java
            resources
        }
   }
   ```

***tl;dr***

```groovy
apply plugin: 'java'

// apply the runtimeClasspath from "test" sourceSet to the new one
// to include any needed assets: test, main, test-dependencies and main-dependencies
sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        // not necessary but nice for IDEa's
        java
        resources

        compileClasspath += sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
        // somehow this redeclaration is needed, but should be irrelevant
        // since runtimeClasspath always expands compileClasspath
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
    }
}

// define custom test task for running integration tests
task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
}
tasks.integrationTest.dependsOn(tasks.test)
```

referring to:

- [gradle java chapter 45.7.1. Source set properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#N1569A)
- [gradle java chapter 45.7.3. Some source set examples](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#N1582C)

Unfortunatly, the example code on [github.com/gradle/gradle/subprojects/docs/src/samples/java/customizedLayout/build.gradle](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/docs/src/samples/java/customizedLayout/build.gradle) or […/gradle/…/withIntegrationTests/build.gradle](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/docs/src/samples/java/withIntegrationTests/build.gradle) seems not to handle this or has a different / more complex / for me no clearer solution anyway!

Comment: (!) as it turns out, the single use of sourceSet enhancements without configurations or output results in a make error in idea after initally opening a project. the build dependency (here: test) for the new "module" (here: integrationTest) isn't available upon first `compileTestJava`

Comment: `classesDir` was migrated to `classesDirs` on gradle 5

Comment: thanks for the hint @deFreitas, I marked the answer as outdated

Answer (score 10):

The [nebula-facet](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-project-plugin#nebula-facet-plugin) plugin eliminates the boilerplate:

```
apply plugin: 'nebula.facet'
facets {
    integrationTest {
        parentSourceSet = 'test'
    }
}
```

For integration tests specifically, even [this is done for you](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-project-plugin#nebula-integtest-plugin), just apply:

```
apply plugin: 'nebula.integtest'
```

The Gradle plugin portal links for each are:

1. [nebula.facet](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/nebula.facet)
2. [nebula.integtest](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/nebula.integtest)

Answer (score 7):

If you're using

- Gradle 5.x, have a look at [Documentation Section "Testing Java > Configuring integration tests](https://docs.gradle.org/5.2.1/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:configuring_java_integration_tests)
  Example 14 and 15 for details (both for Groovy and Kotlin DSL, either which one you prefer)

  - alt: "current" Gradle doc link at [2](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:configuring_java_integration_tests), but might defer in future, you should have a look at if examples changes)
- for Gradle 4 have a look at ancient version [3](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:configuring_java_integration_tests) which is close near to what [@Spina posted in 2012](/questions/11581419/11581420#11581420)

To get IntelliJ to recognize custom sourceset as test sources root:

```
plugin {
    idea
}

idea {
    module {
        testSourceDirs = testSourceDirs + sourceSets["intTest"].allJava.srcDirs
        testResourceDirs = testResourceDirs + sourceSets["intTest"].resources.srcDirs
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what works for me as of Gradle 4.0.

```
sourceSets {
  integrationTest {
    compileClasspath += sourceSets.test.compileClasspath
    runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
  }
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
  description = "Runs the integration tests."
  group = 'verification'
  testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
  classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
}
```

As of version 4.0, Gradle now uses separate classes directories for each language in a source set. So if your build script uses `sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir`, you'll see the following deprecation warning.

> Gradle now uses separate output directories for each JVM language, but this build assumes a single directory for all classes from a source set. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0

To get rid of this warning, just switch to `sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs` instead. For more information, see the [Gradle 4.0 release notes](https://docs.gradle.org/4.0/release-notes.html#detecting-test-classes-for-custom-test-tasks).

Comment: switch to <hmm> ?? Your before and after are the same.

Answer (score 1):

I gather the documentation wasn't great back in 2012 when this question was asked, but for anyone reading this in 2020+: There's now a whole section in the docs about [how to add a source set for integration tests](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:configuring_java_integration_tests). You really should read it instead of copy/pasting code snippets here and banging your head against the wall trying to figure out why an answer from 2012-2016 doesn't quite work.

The answer is most likely simple but more nuanced than you may think, and the exact code you'll need is likely to be different from the code I'll need. For example, do you want your integration tests to use the same dependencies as your unit tests?

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to configure your tests to run with jUnit:

```
task integrationTest(type: Test) {
   ...
   useJunitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for Kotlin (build.gradle.**kts**):

```kotlin
sourceSets {
    create("uiTest") {
        // Adds files from the main source set to the compilation and runtime classpaths of this new source set
        // sourceSets.main.output is a collection of all the directories containing compiled main classes and resources
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.get().output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.get().output
    }
}

// Makes the uiTestImplementation configuration extend from testImplementaion,
// which means that all the declared dependencies of the test code (and transitively the main as well)
// also become dependencies of this new source set
val uiTestImplementation by configurations.getting {
    extendsFrom(configurations.testImplementation.get())
}
val uiTestRuntimeOnly by configurations.getting {
    extendsFrom(configurations.testRuntimeOnly.get())
}
```

Bonus:

```kotlin
val uiTest = task<Test>("uiTest") {
    description = "Runs UI tests."
    group = "verification"

    testClassesDirs = sourceSets["uiTest"].output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets["uiTest"].runtimeClasspath

    testLogging {
        events(TestLogEvent.PASSED)
    }
}

tasks.check { dependsOn(uiTest) }
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm new to Gradle, using Gradle 6.0.1 JUnit 4.12. Here's what I came up with to solve this problem.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
repositories { jcenter() }

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
       srcDirs = ['src']
    }
  }
  test {
    java {
      srcDirs = ['tests']
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that the main source and test source is referenced separately, one under `main` and one under `test`.

The `testImplementation` item under `dependencies` is only used for compiling the source in `test`. If your main code actually had a dependency on JUnit, then you would also specify `implementation` under `dependencies`.

I had to specify the `repositories` section to get this to work, I doubt that is the best/only way.

Comment: idk why this  answer is displayed first for me. Sorry, but you haven't added any new sourcesets and thus missed the question.

Comment: But then your answer solved **my** problem ;-)