# Adding an additional test suite to Gradle

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, integration-testing, gradle

I am attempting to add Gradle (1.4) to an existing project that has multiple test suites. The standard unit test located in `src/test/java` ran successfully, but I am having trouble setting up a task to run the JUnit test located in `src/integration-test/java`.

When I run `gradle intTest` I get several `cannot find symbol` errors for classes in `src/main`. This leads me to believe that the dependencies are not set up correctly. How do I setup `intTest` so that it will run my JUnit integration tests?

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6

sourceSets {
    integration {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/integration-test/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/integration-test/resources'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring', version: '3.0.7')

    testCompile(group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+')
    testCompile(group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-all', version: '1.+')
    testCompile(group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version: '1.+')
    testCompile(group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: '3.0.7.RELEASE')

    integrationCompile(group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+')
    integrationCompile(group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-all', version: '1.+')
    integrationCompile(group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version: '1.+')
    integrationCompile(group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: '3.0.7.RELEASE')
}


task intTest(type: Test) {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integration.output.classesDir
    classpath += sourceSets.integration.runtimeClasspath
}
```

***Details:*** Gradle 1.4

***Solution:*** I had not set the compile classpath for the integration test source set (see below). In my I code I set the compile class path to `sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath` so that I don't have the duplicate dependencies for "integrationCompile"

```
sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/integration-test/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/integration-test/resources'
        }
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a new sourceset to Gradle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581419/how-do-i-add-a-new-sourceset-to-gradle)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the "integration" sourceSet has not configured its compile and runtime classpath. That's why it can't find the classes from your main sourceset. you can configure the compile and runtime classpath in the following way:

```
sourceSets {
    integTest {
        java.srcDir file('src/integration-test/java')
        resources.srcDir file('src/integration-test/resources')
        compileClasspath = sourceSets.main.output + configurations.integTest
        runtimeClasspath = output + compileClasspath
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I only needed to explicitly set the `compileClasspath`. The Runtime classpath is automatically setup as `classes + compileClasspath`

Comment: In Gradle 1.6 you won't find `classes`. Use `output` instead.

Answer (score 6):

In most cases you want to use the same dependencies as your unit tests as well as some new ones. This will add the dependencies of your unit tests on top of the existing ones for integration tests (if any).

```
sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.test.compileClasspath
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you link some documentation to support this? Thanks

Comment: @MikeRylander documentation about what in particular? If it's about the `+=` operator, you can see that `FileCollection` has a `plus` method to support overriding the `+` and `+=` operator: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCollection.html

Comment: I see that the integrationTest source set is extending the test classpath, but what is the second code block doing?

Comment: @MikeRylander Ah, sorry that was not meant to be part of the post. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
test {
    exclude '**/*IntegrationTest*'
    ...
}

task testIntegration(type: Test) {
    include '**/*IntegrationTest*'
    ...
}
```