# Define a sourceset for all java sub-projects

Tags: gradle, source-sets

I wonder if it is possible to define a source set in gradle (e.g. integrationTests) that can be applied to all sub-projects that use the 'java' plugin?

Something like

```
sourceSets {
    integTest {
        java.srcDir file('src/integration-test/java')
        resources.srcDir file('src/integration-test/resources')
        compileClasspath = sourceSets.main.output + configurations.integTest
        runtimeClasspath = output + compileClasspath
    }
}
```

as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741004/adding-an-additional-test-suite-to-gradle) applied to all java sub-projects?

Thanks for useful hints!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter the subprojects of your build by applied plugin. In your example this would look like this:

```
def javaProjects() {
    subprojects.findAll { project -> 
        project.plugins.hasPlugin('java') 
    }
}

configure(javaProjects()) {
    sourceSets {
        integTest {
            java.srcDir file('src/integration-test/java')
            resources.srcDir file('src/integration-test/resources')
            compileClasspath = sourceSets.main.output + configurations.integTest
            runtimeClasspath = output + compileClasspath
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Strangely this does not work for me. When I print the `plugins` object of each subproject all I get is `org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.IdeaPlugin`, which is also strange because I'm not using that plugin anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Because the root project's build script is evaluated before the subprojects' build scripts, `subprojects.findAll{project -> project.plugins.hasPlugin('java')}` does not work (at least in Gradle 4.8.1, which I am using).

Instead, you can register a callback in the root project which will be called each time a plugin is applied in a subproject:

```
subprojects {
    plugins.withId('java', { _ ->
        sourceSets {
            integTest {
                java.srcDir file('src/integration-test/java')
                resources.srcDir file('src/integration-test/resources')
                compileClasspath = sourceSets.main.output + configurations.integTest
                runtimeClasspath = output + compileClasspath
            }
        }
    })
}
```