# With Gradle jvm-test-suite, the integrationTest suite can not access kotlin internal Apis

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I am trying to use the gradle [JVM test suite plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jvm_test_suite_plugin.html) to perform integration test for my Kotlin project. Some of the classes and apis are `internal` visibility.

I followed the sample code to create new test suite `integrationTest`:

```kotlin
testing {
    suites { 
        val integrationTest by registering(JvmTestSuite::class) { 
            dependencies {
                implementation(project) 
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

But the source code under `src/integrationTest/kotlin` could not see `internal` classes in project main. I understand that the test suite of `integrationTest` is not in the same module with project main.

My questions are:

1. why this behavior is not consistent with the default test suite `test` which can access internal classes in project main?
2. If this is by design, how can I workaround this to make internal classes visible to test suite of `integrationTest`?

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem. Found an answer here: [Adding an additional test suite to Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741004/adding-an-additional-test-suite-to-gradle) seems you need to add

> compileClasspath += sourceSets["main"].runtimeClasspath