# Gradle: custom source set as dependency for the main and test ones

Tags: java, gradle, classpath, source-sets

I've created custom source set in Gradle project to keep all generated code:

```
sourceSets {
  generated {
    java {
      srcDir 'src/generated/java'
    }
    resources {
      srcDir 'src/generated/resources'
    }
  }
}
```

I want to make the result of this source set's code compilation available at compile and run time for `main` and `test` source sets.

What's the right semantic way to do it in Gradle?

**UPDATE:**

As suggested here: [How do I add a new sourceset to Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581419/how-do-i-add-a-new-sourceset-to-gradle) doesn't work for me, I still get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` when I launch my app (though compilation and unit tests run fine). Here is what I tried:

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    compileClasspath += sourceSets.generated.output
    runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.generated.output
  }

  test {
    compileClasspath += sourceSets.generated.output
    runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.generated.output
  }
}
```

Comment: there is an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581419/how-do-i-add-a-new-sourceset-to-gradle

Comment: That question is a little bit different and doesn't solve my problem, I still get `ClassNotFoundException` when I launch my app. Please, see updated question.

Comment: You'd have to provide more information, e.g. how exactly you launch the app, what class is not found, etc.

Comment: can you add the stacktrace to the question?

Comment: It's a Spring 4 project with Spring Boot enabled. As build result I get single self-executable JAR with all dependencies packaged in it. As I can see now, missing generated class doesn't present in the resulting JAR. Investigating...

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser is there a way to explicitly say gradle that I want the `*.class` files from `generated` source set to be included into resulting JAR? Or I should create a custom task that produces JAR for `generated` source set (as [here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#N125AE)) and then add this JAR as dependency to the main `compile` configuration.

Comment: `jar { from sourceSets.generated.output }`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        compileClasspath += generated.output
        runtimeClasspath += generated.output
    }
}
```

Same for the `test` source set.

Comment: Thanks, Peter! For everyone who face similar issue: as turned out the issue was with packaging JAR, not with specifying dependencies, please see Peter's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161845/gradle-custom-source-set-as-dependency-for-the-main-and-test-ones#comment31855557_21161845).