# Gradle Include Source Files

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, javac, build.gradle

I have a project in which I have two different 'sub-projects', the main library and a compiler for a programming language in a directory structure like this:

```
- build.gradle
- src
  - library
  - compiler
  - ...
```

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
sourceSets
{
    library
    {
        java
        {
            srcDir 'src/library'
            srcDir 'src/asm'
        }
    }
    compiler
    {
        java
        {
            srcDir 'src/compiler'
        }
    }
    //...
}

// ...

task buildLib(type: Jar, dependsOn: 'classes') {
    from sourceSets.library.output
    classifier = 'dyvil-library'
}

task buildCompiler(type: Jar, dependsOn: 'classes') {
    from sourceSets.compiler.output
    classifier = 'dyvil-compiler'
}
```

My problem is that whenever I try to run the `buildCompiler` task, the build fails and the Java Compiler gives me hundreds of errors in places where the compiler source code references classes in the library. I already tried to make the compiler dependant on the library classes like this:

```
task buildCompiler(type: Jar, dependsOn: [ 'classes', 'libraryClasses' ]) {
    from sourceSets.compiler.output
    classifier = 'dyvil-compiler'
}
```

But that did not help. I know that I could theoretically copy the `srcDirs` from `sourceSets.library` into `sourceSets.compiler` like this:

```
compiler
{
    java
    {
        srcDir 'src/library'
        srcDir 'src/asm'
        srcDir 'src/compiler'
    }
}
```

But that seems like a bad idea for obvious reasons.

Is there another way to include the source files from the library when compiling the compiler (*duh*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a similar question [on SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161845/gradle-custom-source-set-as-dependency-for-the-main-and-test-ones).

I replicated your situation locally and the fix was to add a line to the sourceSets for `compiler` as follows:

```
compiler
{
    java {
        srcDir 'src/compiler'
    }
    compileClasspath += library.output
}
```