# Gradle how to build extra source sourceSets?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I ask the command to build class in extra part of source set.

Here is the [build.gradle](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/phrasal/blob/master/build.gradle) in question.

```
// Configure build targets
sourceSets {
  main {
    java.srcDirs = ['src/' ]
    resources.srcDirs = ['resources/']
  }
  test {
    java.srcDirs = ['test/']
    resources.srcDirs = ['test-resources/','src-cc']
  }
  extra {
    java.srcDirs = ['src-extra/']
    resources.srcDirs = ['resources/']
  }
}
```

I need class that in src-extra. However, run `gradle installDist` produce a jar in build/libs that does not contain any class in src-extra.

How should I get to build those extra class ? 
Which command I should type in my Terminal in order to build those source code in src-extra.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a new sourceset to Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581419/how-do-i-add-a-new-sourceset-to-gradle)

Comment: @chenrui I am looking for specific command (which you type in terminal) to build source code in src-extra so I can use the software (as end-user).  I am not interesting in modify source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `gradle task --all` to list all task.

You may see:

> compileExtraJava - Compiles extra Java source.

So, the command to build extra is

```
 gradle compileExtraJava
```