# Separating integration vs. unit tests in gradle based on abstract class

Tags: gradle, groovy, junit, spock

I'm trying to separate my gradle/spock tests into two groups:

1. unit tests
2. integration tests

My attempt was with jUnit's `@Category`. In `build.gradle` I created task for integration/e2e tests:

```
task e2eTest(type: Test) {
    useJUnit {
        includeCategories 'com.foo.bar.baz.E2ESpec'
    }
}
```

And marked my base abstract class with `@Category(E2ESpec)`, but it doesn't work.

I've noticed that inheritance works, but only with single level inheritance:

```
@Category(E2ESpec)
abstract class AbstractSpec {...}

class ActualSpec extends AbstractSpec {...}
```

but doesn't work for cases like:

```
@Category(E2ESpec)
abstract class AbstractSpect {...}

abstract class AnotherAbstractSpec extends AbstractSpec {...}

class ActualSpec extends AnotherAbstractSpec {...}
```

Any idea how to fix it?

PS. I've many classes extending `AbstractSpec` and new classes appears, so I don't want `@Category` on each spec. Maybe pure gradle solution exists?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new sourceset for integration tests, with a corresponding task. See [How do I add a new sourceset to Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581419/how-do-i-add-a-new-sourceset-to-gradle)