# gradle integration test not working, unit test running twice

Tags: java, gradle, integration-testing

I have this root **build.gradle**

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

subprojects  {

    apply plugin: 'java'

    group 'me.someone'
    version '1.0.0'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }

}
```

Then I have this child **build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'eclipse'
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.0.1.RELEASE"
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version "1.0.5.RELEASE"
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile project(':foo-jar')

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.18.3'

}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
        }
    }

    test {
        java.srcDir file('src/int/java')
    }

    itest {
        java {
            srcDir file('src/itest/java')
        }
        //resources.srcDir 'src/itest/resources'
    }
}


test {
    testLogging {
        showStandardStreams = true
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
        exceptionFormat = 'full'
    }   
}

task itest(type: Test) {
  testLogging {
        showStandardStreams = true
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
        exceptionFormat = 'full'
   }
   itest.mustRunAfter test
}

check.dependsOn itest

bootRun {
    main = 'me.someone.BarServiceApplication'
}
```

The issue is unit test runs twice but not the integration test. Why is unit test running twice but not integration test? My understanding is when I provided the source folder of integration test, it should run the integration test as well.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581419/how-do-i-add-a-new-sourceset-to-gradle?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Your task `itest` needs to have its [`testClassesDirs` configured](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:testClassesDirs), that is why it is currently running your unit tests twice. It might also need the [`classpath` configured](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:classpath).

And you should have a look at the Gradle documentation on [how to do integration tests](https://docs.gradle.org/4.8/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:configuring_java_integration_tests) for all the details.