# why new sourceset resources not in buildDir in gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I have declared

```
        sourceSets {
            micro {
                resources.srcDir file('src/micro/resources')
            }
        }
```

but

> micro/resources

not copied to ${**buildDir**}/**resources**/**micro**.

I want to add micro sourceSet to classpath. Thereby I can run from eclipse or from gradleConsole.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Is there anything that depends on the resources in this `SourceSet`? Otherwise there is no reason for gradle to evaluate this `SourceSet`. You can try the manually call `gradle processMicroResources` to see if the `SourceSet` is configured correctly but you will have to create some dependency if you want it to be a part of your regular build.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might not be using the correct syntax: [How do I add a new sourceset to Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581419/how-do-i-add-a-new-sourceset-to-gradle)
Maybe you could try like this:

```
sourceSets {
  micro{
    resources {
      srcDir 'src/micro/resources'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I was more thinking about the use of file('...')? @Slok