# Adding integration tests to Kotlin project using the Kotlin Gradle DSL

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I would like to add an additional "source set" to a Kotlin project that will contain integration tests. I have seen a few posts that talk about doing it for either a vanilla Java project or for Kotlin but using Groovy rather than the Kotlin Gradle DSL.

**In summary, using the Kotlin Gradle DSL:**

- **how to add an additional "source set" that can contain Kotlin code, Java code & resources for the purpose of separating integration tests from regular unit tests?**
- **how to add an additional task and configuration to run the integration tests separately from unit tests?**

I would expect the directory structure to look something like:

```
src
   main
      java
      kotlin
      resources
   test
      java
      kotlin
      resources
   integration
      java
      kotlin
      resources
```

Related:

- https://ryanharrison.co.uk/2018/07/25/kotlin-add-integration-test-module.html
- https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/gradle/getting-started-with-gradle-integration-testing/
- [How do I add a new sourceset to Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581419/how-do-i-add-a-new-sourceset-to-gradle)

Thanks

Comment: I just created a question that's related to yours. I was also able to figure out how to get it to work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52904603/integration-tests-with-gradle-kotlin-dsl/52906232#52906232

Answer (score 1):

First, create source set and configuration:

```
sourceSets {
    create("intTest") {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.get().output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.get().output
    }
}

val intTestImplementation: Configuration by configurations.getting {
    extendsFrom(configurations.implementation.get())
}

val intTestRuntimeOnly: Configuration by configurations.getting {
    extendsFrom(configurations.runtimeOnly.get())
}
```

And then, create the task to run them:

```
val integrationTest = task<Test>("integrationTest") {
    description = "Runs integration tests"
    group = "verification"

    testClassesDirs = sourceSets["intTest"].output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets["intTest"].runtimeClasspath
    shouldRunAfter("test")
}
```

Also, you can add dependencies to be used by the new source set. For instance:

```
intTestImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$junitVersion")
intTestRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$junitVersion")
```

Answer (score -1):

You must add following configuration to your build.gradle file

```
configurations {
    integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom implementation
    integrationTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom runtimeOnly
}


dependencies {
    intTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    ...
}

sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        kotlin {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
            srcDir file('src/integrationTest/kotlin')
        }
    }
}

task integrationTest(type: Test, dependsOn: []) {
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

source:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:configuring_java_integration_tests