# How do I create an additional Kotlin SourceSet using Gradle with Kotlin DSL

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I want to create a test lib source set, `src/tlib/kotlin` that "sits *between*" main and test. I have this, but I'm not sure why I would use `java` source dir for kotlin, and I need to get it depending on my main sources

```
sourceSets {
   create("tlib").java.srcDir("src/tlib/kotlin")
}
```

**update**

```
Calebs-MBP:phg-entity calebcushing$ ./gradlew build
e: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
    class phg.entity.AbstractEntityBase, unresolved supertypes: org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable
> Task :compileTlibKotlin FAILED
```

close

```
sourceSets {
    val main by getting
    val tlib by creating {
        java {
            srcDir("src/tlib/kotlin")
            compileClasspath += main.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output
        }
    }
    val test by getting {
        java {
            compileClasspath += tlib.output
            runtimeClasspath += tlib.output
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    val compile by getting
    val runtime by getting
    val tlibCompile by getting {
        extendsFrom(compile)
    }
    val tlibRuntime by getting {
        extendsFrom(runtime)
    }
    val testCompile by getting {
        extendsFrom(tlibCompile)
    }
    val testRuntime by getting {
        extendsFrom(tlibRuntime)
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("${project.group}:constant:[0.1,1.0)")
    api("javax.validation:validation-api")
    api("javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api")
    api("org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons") // has the missing dependency
```

Comment: This test library code shared by the test code and other modules thing has been codified by Gradle now in the java-test-fixtures plugin.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A number of things are properly taken care of by the plugins, so the addition is really about configuring the sourceSet classpath and wiring configurations.

Here is a short answer showing the classpath config and one configuration extension:

```
sourceSets {
    val tlib by creating {
        // The kotlin plugin will by default recognise Kotlin sources in src/tlib/kotlin
        compileClasspath += sourceSets["main"].output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets["main"].output
    }
}

configurations {
    val tlibImplementation by getting {
        extendsFrom(configurations["implementation"])
    }
}
```

Comment: Newer versions of Gradle have typesafe accessors so now you can do `sourceSets.main.get().output` and `extendsFrom(configurations.implementation.get())`.

Answer (score 3):

There a similar question for Groovy
[How do I add a new sourceset to Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581419/how-do-i-add-a-new-sourceset-to-gradle)

```
sourceSets {
  val main by getting
  val test by getting
  val tlib by creating {
    java {
      srcDir("src/tlib/kotlin")
      compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
      runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
    }
  }
}

configurations {
  val testCompile by getting
  val testRuntime by getting
  val tlibCompile by getting {
    extendsFrom(testCompile)
  }
  val tlibRuntime by getting {
    extendsFrom(testRuntime)
  }
}
```

Comment: but how do I make it depend on main, and how do I make test depend on it?

Comment: hmm... somehow my classpath isn't getting all of my deps, I updated the question

Comment: make sure you do not miss transitive dependency. `implementation` dependency is not transitive, use api where needed

Comment: uh... isn't that what I have? the missing dep is pulled in with `api`