# "Kotlin Not Configured" when i create a new .kt file

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

[file in main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21M6P.png) [file in another package you can see the println is red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cdJ1.png) I am new to kotlin and intellij ide. The main .kt file or any other .kt file created in the src/main file seems to work fine . But when i create another package in src and in it a new .kt file it shows kotlin not working.I tried clearing caches and starting but it didn't solve the problem . I have also reviewed other solutions but nothing seems to work for me.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: could you be more specific like, what build system are you using , what jdk, , what kotlin version also screenshot if it it possible

Comment: kotlin version 1.5.10 jdk version 16

Comment: Why do you create a separate directory for sources? If you use Gradle you must configure sources in Gradle files by the source sets, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11581420/2000323